# Dinamically separate target in different flat files not working in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a table which I need to split dinamically into multiple plain text tables (tab separated).

My source has a field that I plan to use. As an example my table has the following columns:

`ID`, `CATEGORY`, `NAME`, `OFFICE`, `POSITION`, `SALARY`

Target files would have the columns

`ID`, `Name`, `Category`, `Position`, `Salary`

and I will have one file per office.

I am using a Sorter transformation to sort by `OFFICE`, `CATEGORY`, `ID`

Then a expression transformation where I add column `PREV_OFFICE` and `FILENAME`, and the variable `V_OFFICE`. They are defined as:

```
PREV_OFFICE := ISNULL(V_OFFICE, ' ', V_OFFICE)
V_OFFICE := OFFICE
FILENAME := 'Employees_' || OFFICE || '.xls'
```

Then a Transaction control transformation with Transaction Control Condition as:

```
IIF(PREV_OFFICE != OFFICE, TC_COMMIT_BEFORE, TC_CONTINUE_TRANSACTION)
```

And finally the target with fields

`ID`, `Name`, `Category`, `Position`, `Salary`, `FileName`

So far according to documentation.

**However it is not writing down separate files for each Office.**

These are my settings for the Session Task in WorkFlow manager:

```
Merge Type: No Merge
Append if Exists: unchecked
Create Target Directory: unchecked
Header Options: Output Filed Name
Header Command: --blank--
Footer Command: --blank--
Output Type: File
Output file directory: $PMTargetFileDir\
Output file: Employees.xls
Reject file directory: $PMBadFileDir\
Reject file: shortcut_to_employees_xls1.bad
```

All data, including the `FileName` field is written down in `Employees.xls`, (format is right), and no `Employees_<office>.xls` files are created.

I have checked and indeed `PREV_OFFICE` and `OFFICE` have the expected values (they are different when there is a new value for `OFFICE`).

---

On a second issue, each file should be sent to a different FTP location, using a table with the following columns:

`OFFICE`, `FTP_SERVER`, `FTP_USER`, `FTP_PASSWD`, `FTP_PATH`

Currently I am using a LookUp Tranformation to get these fields, and creating, when `PREV_OFFICE != OFFICE`, the shell script instructions for moving each file (and null otherwise). The instructions are okay, but I get too many blank lines. (BTW this proofs the `PREV_OFFICE` and `OFFICE` fields are right for the purpose)

I have attempted to filter out the undesired lines but the validation fails claiming that two flows would be governed by one Transaction Control.

Comment: You wanted to move the data to a file or table ?

Answer (score 1):

Tick the Filename port option on your target which will generate a new target with same filename as the input port value you connect to there